# Bash function call from script file fails, while call from terminal succeeds

Tags: shell-script, files, source, bash-functions

In Ubuntu 16.04 with Bash I created a file `$HOME/ulcwe/software_internal.sh` that contains a function `rse()` without a call. The file is sourced in `~/.bashrc` (which was sourced by itself) and I can can call `rse` from anywhere in the terminal and it will run without error.

Yet I tried to run [this script file](https://github.com/benqzq/nwsm/blob/master/nwsm.sh) that contains a call to `rse` in line 36, and I get this error:

> line 36: rse: command not found

Why does the function called successfully in manual call (typing and executing `rse` in Bash) but not from the Bash script and how could I call it successfully from the script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to make sure that the function is available to the script.  You can do this in two ways:

1. `source` the file that contains the function definition, or
2. `export` the function before calling the script (`export -f rse` would export the function).

Functions, just like shell variables, are not part of the environment that gets inherited by scripts.  Shell variables has to be exported so that they become environment variables, and `bash` functions can likewise be exported.

Exported functions are not callable by *any* process, just by other `bash` scripts.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question to clarify something I forgot to clarify: I sourced the file containing the function from `bashrc` and then sourced the relevant `bashrc` itself. I am surprised it still isn't enough to call the function from the aforementioned script-file (but enough for manual call from terminal).

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now, although the function-file is sourced from `bashrc` it isn't exported, hence not available for **sub-processes** like the script file I ran. Thus, I should export the function file and in `bashrc`, and not just source it there.

Comment: After the function definition, use `export -f tdm` (or `export -f rse` or whatever the function was called).

Comment: Did that (in `bashrc`) then the function ran indeed from the script. Thanks.